# RFID~RC522 module not reading some cards

Tags: rfid

this is my first question here and I am kinda lost.

I have a RC522 RFID module hooked up to a Raspberry PI 0 V1.1, and I have a TAG and a CARD (which I got with the module when I bought it) and I have 3 CARDS that I bought separately.

My issue is that my RFID module is reading only the card and the tag that came in the same package, and it is not reading the new cards that I bought separately.

[image: These are the 3 cards that I bought separately]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They are probably a different frequency of cards, you would need to provide links to what you have bought for much more help.

Comment: I bought it from a local store, not from Internet.

Comment: There are multiple different card protocols and frequency's used for RFID cards, i would look at what ever documentation you have to see if they should be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RC-522 reader (and reader / writer) is designed to work on the 13.56MHz electromagnetic field using the ISO 14443A standard tags.  These are also known as S50 or S70 cards going by the names Mifare1 S50 / S70, MIFARE Ultralight, Mifare Pro, and MIFARE DESFire (though other card manufacturers are available).

It may be worth checking you do not have a MF RC500 or MF RC530 as they are different and cannot handle some cards.  Sunfounder have a full spec sheet that details protocol / chip registers etc [here (109 pages)](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/images/c/c6/MFRC522_datasheet.pdf).

I would guess you have 125Khz cards going by the colour, size and 10 digit number printed on them that are often used for door entry.  These are not programmable and come ready coded with the number electronically matching the printed details.